# Display form fields based on user type with Meteor Useraccount package

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

Could anyone help me to figure out how to get around this please?

Here is the scenario: 
Assume there are three types of user namely **student**, **teacher**, and **parent** that I want to save in my collection using `useraccounts` package.

**Problem**

In my `AccountsTemplates.addField({})`, I'd like to configure it in such way that signup form is displaying **3 fields for student**, **four for teacher**, and **5 fields for parent** with the help of `type: hidden` property depending on who the user has chosen to be from these three below options.

*Who Am I?*

*Parent*

```
<a href="/new-account/parent">Parent</a>
```

*student*

*Teacher*

**Attempted solutions**

1. I've tried with `FlowRouter` parameter and use the value provided by the user from the above options but the thing is `AccountTemplate` is suggested to be place in `/lib` whereby it's can be accessed both by the **client** and **server** but the problem is `FlowRouter.getParam()` doesn't work on server side.
2. With `pub/sub`, in `account-config.js` I wrote this

   `if(Meteor.isServer){
     Meteor.publish('getParam', function(param){ 
      console.log(param)
    })}else if(Meteor.isClient){
      console.log(FlowRouter.getParam('user-type')
    }`

And in 
`routes.js`

```
FlowRouter.route('/new-account/:user-type', { 
    action(){
     Meteor.subscribe('getParam', FlowRouter.getParam('user-type');
      // because here  .getParam can be accessed.
 }
}
```

It's just worked fine and reactive on server side but on `client` side, `undefined`

Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Which "useraccounts" package exactly do you use? I see many useraccounts packages on https://atmospherejs.com/?q=useraccount

Comment: I'm using `useraccounts:bootstrap`
Thanks

Comment: I'd want to be able to do something like this


`if(userType==='parent'){
    AccountsTemplate.addFields({
       //add fields for parent 
    })
}else if (userType==='student''){
    //Generate this form 
}
...
`

Comment: Ok it seems, that you just have some false placement of client/server code (and I still don't see, why you need a publication for that). Can you post a little more of your code? Something that fits https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve then I think this could work out easily.